# I want to highlight the syntax of my MutiAutoCompleteTextView for each time text is changed

Tags: android, textwatcher

**I want to highlight the syntax of the MutiAutoCompleteTextView for each time text is changed, I have tried this but my app freezes at run time, please help me how I can do so. **

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView Code;
TextHighlighter Highlighter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    Code = findViewById(R.id.Code);
    Highlighter = new TextHighlighter();
    Highlighter.setLanguage(Highlighter.JAVA);
    String text=Highlighter.getHighlightedText(Code.getText().toString());
    Code.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    
    Code.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher);

}

private TextWatcher TextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable p1)
    {
        if(Code.length() !=0)
        {
            String text=Highlighter.getHighlightedText(Code.getText().toString());
            Code.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
        }
    }
    
    
};

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app freezes because when you set text using `Code.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));` your `afterTextChanged` will called immediately. So it will run as infinite loop. You can control this flow with a flag.

For ex:

```
boolean isHighlighted = false;
private TextWatcher TextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable p1)
    {
        String text=Highlighter.getHighlightedText(Code.getText().toString());
        if(Code.length() !=0 && !isHighlighted)
        {
            isHighlighted == true;
            Code.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
            //setText will resets cursor position, so you have to move the cursor to the end. 
            Code.setSelection(text.length)
        } else {
            isHighlighted = false;
        }
    }        
};
```

Comment: But my cursor gets reset for every new character or word i type.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Great!! Thank you.